# How to listen to keyspace events using Spring Data Redis with a GCP managed cluster?

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using secondary indexes with Redis thanks to Spring Data Redis `@Indexed` annotations. My entry has a TTL.
This has a side effect of keeping the indexes after the expiration of the main entry. This is expected, and [Spring can listen to keyspace expiry events to remove those indexes once the main TTL is done.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693774/spring-redis-indexes-not-deleted-after-main-entry-expires)

However, enabling the listening to keyspace expiry events with Spring, I face the following error at startup:

```
ERR unknown command 'CONFIG'
```

This is how I configured the listener:

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is linked to the fact that the Redis cluster is managed, and as such remote clients can't call CONFIG on it. When enabling the Spring keyspace event listener, it tries to configure Redis to emit keyspace expiry events, by setting the `notify-keyspace-events` config key to "Ex".

The workaround to this is:

1. Configure your MemoryStore on GCP, adding the `notify-keyspace-events` key with "Ex" as value.
2. Use `@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP, keyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter = "")` for your client configuration. [The explicitely empty String prevents Spring from trying to override the remote configuration.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations)

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to remember that the listener must listen notifications from all master nodes.

Please see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1782

Adding lettuce properties to connect with cluster solves problem. My config:

```
  data:
    redis:
      password: your-password
      ssl:
        enabled: true
      cluster:
        nodes: node-address
      lettuce:
        cluster:
          refresh:
            dynamic-refresh-sources: false
            period: PT1S
        pool:
          max-active: 15
          max-wait: -1
          max-idle: -1
          min-idle: 5
```